# How to convert using PANDOC a markdown file to rtf

Tags: command-line-interface, markdown, pandoc, rtf, file-conversion

I am new to pandoc and I am strugling to get a file convesion done. I want to convert a markdown file to a rtf file.

```
pandoc -f markdown -f rtf 1.md -o file.rtf
```

I am using the following command, however it just does not do the work correctly, as it is not beind correctly displayed when opening the file...

[image]

I also tried to replace the second flag with `-s`, however it also did not work:

```
pandoc -f markdown -s rtf 1.md -o file.rtf
```

I get the following notification, when I try to do that:

`pandoc: rtf: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command has too many arguments.

Try this, removing the `rtf` syntax since that next argument is supposed to be the source file `1.md`.

`pandoc -f markdown -s 1.md -o file.rtf`

Comment: Thank you, it just worked fine here